# Pandas - Read in sheets but exclude some

Tags: python, pandas

Afternoon,

Need some help reading in an excel sheet to a data frame - The file contains multiple sheets but I am only interested in a handful, however the report updates each month and an additional sheet is added to reflect the new month.

Example - The report will have a 'summary', 'info' and then 'Jan-21' , 'Feb-21' etc all the way through to 'Dec-21'

First I tried using `pd.concat(pd.read_excel` with `sheet_name = none` when reading in the file but that brings in the additional sheets and when writing to excel the format is messy.

However if I use  `sheet_name = ['Jan-21','Feb-21']` to specify all the sheets I am after, when I add a future months not yet on the report to the list I get the error "No Sheet Named"

How can I avoid the error and only read in the sheets I need (The months) without having to worry about going back in to update the additionally added sheet each month?

My thoughts are there has got to be a way to either ignore a sheet, del a sheet or if on error resume with what was available? - I'm pretty new to learning this and it's one of the things I haven't been able to solve with a search so help is much appreciated.

full line of code below -

```
Fees_M8rix = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(r" **file path and file** ", sheet_name= ['Jan-21','Feb-21','Mar-21']))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `pd.ExcelFile`:

```
# initialize a file instance
reader = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')

# all possible sheets of interest
sheet_to_read = ['Jan-21','Feb-21','Mar-21']

# choose only existing sheets
actual_sheets = [s for s in reader.sheet_names if s in sheet_to_read]

# read those sheets
dfs = pd.read_excel(reader, sheet_names = actual_sheets)

# close the file instance    
reader.close()
```

Comment: Seems like this requires updating the `sheet_to_read` list manually? I understand the OP wants to dynamically update the list `sheet_name`.

Comment: @gofvonx I understand that OP wants to read 3 sheets, but some might not be in the workbook and throw an error. This sort of checks for the existence of the sheet names before loading, so there's no need to modify the `sheet_to_read` list.

Comment: @QuangHoang The above has worked! I just added on `fees_m8rix = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)` and I'm now only pulling the monthly sheets through whether they exist or not - much appreciated