# I want to ignore the first guildlines sheet and print rest of the sheets

Tags: pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.concat(pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
```

When I tried this code I'm getting all sheet values including gulidness sheet which actually does not have any columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Read in sheets but exclude some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478924/pandas-read-in-sheets-but-exclude-some)

Answer (score 1):

You can read excel file and then specify which sheets you want to read to a dataframe:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')

sheets_dict = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name = xls.sheet_names[1:])

df = pd.concat(sheets_dict.values())
```